# What is the cardinality of the set $\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 \; | \; y > x > 0 , x^x = y^y \}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

As it is clear from the title, what is the cardinality of the set $\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 \; | \; y > x > 0 , x^x = y^y \}$?

Comment: The graph of the function $x \mapsto x^x$ shows that the cardinality is that of an open interval, hence the continuum. For a formal proof, determine the minimum and consider the values left and right to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^x$. Then $f'(x) = x^x(\ln x - 1)$.

For $0 < x < e^{-1}$, $f'(x) < 0$ so $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(0, e^{-1})$. For $e^{-1} < x < \infty$, $f'(x) > 0$ so $f$ is strictly increasing on $(e^{-1}, \infty)$. We also have a critical point for $f(x)$ at $x = e^{-1}$. In fact, this is a local minimum which has value $e^{-e^{-1}}$.

We have $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = 1$ so $f((0, e^{-1})) = (e^{-e^{-1}}, 1)$. Likewise, $f(1) = 1$ so $f((e^{-1}, 1)) = (e^{-e^{-1}}, 1)$. As $f$ is strictly monotone on each of the intervals $(0, e^{-1})$ and $(e^{-1}, 1)$, for any $k \in (e^{-e^{-1}}, 1)$, there is a unique $x_1 \in (0, e^{-1})$ such that $f(x_1) = k$ and a unique $x_2 \in (e^{-1}, 1)$ such that $f(x_2) = k$.

Note that $(x_1, x_2) \in \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y > x > 0, x^x = y^y\}$, so we obtain an injective map $(e^{-e^{-1}}, 1) \to \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y > x > 0, x^x = y^y\}$; in fact, this map is a bijection, but we don't need this.

As $(e^{-e^{-1}}, 1)$ has cardinality of the continuum, so does the set of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Use $x=z^{\frac z{1-z}}$ and $y=z^{\frac 1{1-z}}$ for $0<z<1$. We have $y=zx$, and

$$y^y=z^{\frac y{z-1}}=z^{\frac {z}{z-1}x}=x^x$$